# function_exists php

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function that could receive it's second arg a name of a function.
In order to validate function's name (that will be used in an eval statement) I use function_exists such as:

```
if(function_exists($type)){
    $toEval= $type.'(\''.$file.'\');';
  }else{
```

But if the arg sent is include or require (with 'once' variations) this code fails (function_exists returns false).

Comment: Eval may not be necessary here. `$type($file);` may work as well. But as @CommanderZ says, this whole thing can be indicative of a design flaw

Answer (score 2):

I think you should think whether your application is really designed well. This kind of code often suggests there is something wrong with the overall design. You should also be very careful what you pass into such method. You may end up with some very serious security issues.

```
if($type == 'require' || $type == 'require_once' || .. || function_exists($type)){}
```

Or better

```
$constructs = array('include', 'require', ...);
if(in_array($type, $constructs) || function_exists($type)){};
```

Comment: although I cannot forsee the security issue, I belive your second snippet will do the job quite well, so Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a risk someone might somehow manipulate the $type parameter - which could result in execution of arbitrary code on your server.

Answer (score 1):

`include`, `require` and a number of other calls are language constructs, not functions.

You would have to check for these manually.

See [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) for a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not functions but language constructs:

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/php-take-advantage-of-language-constructs/

If they're acceptable, you should filter them out manually, e.g. using a switch statement:

```
switch( strtolower($type) ){
    case 'echo':
    case 'print':
    case 'include':
       ...
       break;
}
```